# Azure Websites Custom SSL ASP.Net MVC Workaround

Tags: ssl, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service

Currently Azure Websites don't allow custom SSL certificates, but they have wildcard SSL enabled for the *.azurewebsites.net domain. I need a secure login form for my web app, but with no custom SSL, it appears that I'm SOL.

Is there any kind of workaround for this? Would it be possible somehow to have a login form at https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net that creates a forms authentication ticket that will then work at http://mydomain.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of months ago I had exactly the same problem i.e. application was built on Azure Websites, had to run on custom domain other than `*.azurewebsites.net` and had to allow secure login process.

Workaround for that we used was to embed an *iframe* (using secure protocol and `.azurewebsites.net` domain name e.g. `https://oursite.azurewebsites.net/login`) into non-secure page on custom domain (e.g. `http://mysite.com/login`). And entire login process was performed in the *iframe*.

There is one thing which you should be aware of, namely, lots of customers checks whether the page where they provide their credentials was using secure connection or not. In our case, *secure iframe* in non-secure page was causing lots of customer complains. Workaround for that problem was to put a message confirming that the login process uses secure connection. The message made some improvements, however, still certain number of customers complains remained.

I hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks. My application doesn't really deal with any secure information (no financial data or credit cards, etc) just standard login info so I think this workaround will be okay. Hopefully Azure will add custom SSL soon. Anyone looking to help get this feature in place, vote at: http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/3138164-enable-https-ssl-for-web-sites

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer to your question, but Microsoft are very aware that custom mapped SSL to websites is one of the most requested features for Azure websites and they have said they are working on it.
[Scott Hanselman himself confirms it here](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/3138164-enable-https-ssl-for-web-sites)

In the meantime, Tom's answer is a perfectly valid workaround.

One thing I would be very wary of though is with something Tom brings up: the security warning that the browser will present. You'd be amazed how many people freak out when they see that message and don't go any further! We have a fairly active ecommerce site and there have been occasions where we have accidentally used a none secure image path on an SSL page and we have always received emails from customers asking if our site has been hacked or similar!
The disclaimer that Tom mentions is a good idea, but I think it will still put some people off.

Comment: Scott actually DM'd me on Twitter and said they are working on it and that it's high priority.

Answer (score 1):

I am working directly with the WAWS team right now to produce some public guidance for this. A GitHub repository with the requirements is currently being evaluated by the team (I sent it over to them literally 1 hour ago). Hopefully, the solution will be approved and made public within a few weeks.

I can say this - the workaround won't be fully supported or much custom guidance given on its usage aside from the repository and accompanying documentation. SSL is, literally, the #1 priority for the product, and hundreds of people are working insane hours to make it happen for everyone. This workaround should also be considered temporary, as you'll no longer need it once the full SSL functionality is launched.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the ARR on a WebRole solution? I've been in contact with a person from Microsoft about getting this information and he was supposed to provide me the documentation and the necessary files but I haven't heard from him in a while. Thanks for the update. Looking forward to this.

Comment: I implement Brady's solution http://www.bradygaster.com/running-ssl-with-windows-azure-web-sites yesterday. Although this solution works,
we can't use Facebook & Twitter authentication or sharing, because 
the thing redirects to wrong https. Lets say if your site is https://foo.com it redirects to https://foo.azurewebsites.net.